# Sorting a FileList object

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to sort input files using the new File API. The list that it returns seems to be immutable:

```
var x = "";
var files = e.target.files; // FileList object
// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.

files.sort();

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<FileList> has no method 'sort'
```

If I want to read in multiple files at once, but I want them to arrive in order. (`A.csv` is processed before `B.csv`, etc). Is this achievable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[].slice.call(files)` to make it into a real array, then you can use `.sort` on it.

Comment: A new method in ES6 is [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) specifically for this reason. As of date of writing it's only implemented by Firefox 32 and higher.

Comment: Using the ES6 spread operator is another option:

    let files = [...e.target.files].sort();

Comment: But how do you then get it back into the original files object?