# How to change order of files in multiple file input?

Tags: html, file-upload, input

The files are ordered alphabetically by default; is there any way to upload them in the order they were chosen in the file picker instead?

I want to be able to select a primary file and then other extra files in the same input without having to submit more than one input/time.

Comment: You have to use jquery for that to select mulitple files at a time and upload them all together

Comment: Uploading multiple files works fine, but my question is about choosing in what order they're uploaded.

Comment: Therefore you need jquery to assign them in an array or list and than walktrough that list to upload the files

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Comment: It's a normal file input with the multiple attribute. I want the list of files to change according to what files I selected first, instead of them being sorted alphabetically. http://jsfiddle.net/wk9rbouz/

Comment: I wanted the same thing (relying on selection order). For me tho, sorting the fileList by lastModified date works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020593/sorting-a-filelist-object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The files are actually not ordered alphabetically. They are lined in the order of appearance in the file picker (at least that is how current Chrome and Firefox work on Windows 7). You simply had them sorted by name in the picker.

I don't think what you're asking is possible. You could either:

- instruct the user to make sure the primary file is always first in
  the list (however, I believe there is no guarantee of the order by
  browsers).
- create a separate input element for the primary file.
- **(recommended)** display the file names (and/or content) and allow the user to select the file he wishes to be primary. Store that information in some hidden field with JavaScript.