# FileList, FormData() order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am very new to front-end development and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to specify the order of files when it comes to upload. From my fooling around I can tell that when changing the filters on the window explorer, it changes the order in which the files are uploaded. However would there be a way to say I want File 2 selected out of 4 to be the first to get uploaded. I am curious if anything new has been added to any standard

Upload controller:

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', '$log',
function ($http, $log) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
        //$log.debug("file(s)");
        //$log.debug(file);
        var fd = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(file, function (value, key) {
            fd.append(key, value);
        });
        return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                'enctype': "multipart/form-data"
            }
        })
    }; // uploadFileToUrl
}]); // fileUpload
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change order of files in multiple file input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588543/how-to-change-order-of-files-in-multiple-file-input)

Comment: related, but I am curious to see if there have been any updates to do this... in JS or Angular

Comment: Doesn't really matter what framework you use as it's primarily up to the browser and OS. Though, in your code, it looks like `file` is an array that could be reordered before it gets run through the `forEach` call.