# Can I preserve the order of files uploaded on Streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using Python Streamlit's file uploader to upload mutiple files and do some transformation and stitching. However, when I choose multiple files at once, the uploaded files are arranged by alphabetical order so they will be stitched by alphabetical order instead of a custom order. Is it possible to preserve the order in which the files are chosen? Or is there a way I can have some sort of draggable element for users to switch around the order of the files before applying the transformations and stitching? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a [multiselect](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.multiselect) with file names to let the user specify the order.

Comment: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588543/how-to-change-order-of-files-in-multiple-file-input) someone suggests to sort the file list by lastModified date which might be an option.